# Converting IPV4 Address from bytes to String

Tags: java, inetaddress

I currently am trying to create a chat server as an assignment and want each message to contain a header. It will contain ipv4 address followed by a letter then a username

I can easily decode string letters from bytes but now I am struggling to decode an ipv4 address from bytes

the representation so far from the bytes is this

[-64, -88, 1, 5]

which in the ipv4 dotted quad format would be 192.168.1.5

I just need a way to try and decode the four bytes of integers to a string or something along those lines

THANKS :D

Answer (score 11):

[`InetAddress.getByAddress(bytes).getHostAddress()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getByAddress%28byte%5B%5D%29)?

Answer (score 0):

That is easily done like this:

```
byte[] address = ...;
String addressStr = "";
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
{
    int t = 0xFF & address[i];
    addressStr += "." + t;
}
addressStr = addressStr.substring(1);
```